# The simplest way to have a strongly typed array with 2 datatypes?

Tags: c#

I don't want any sorting or anything fancy. I simply want 2 columns the left with names and the right with numbers.

Something like this:

```
string/int[,] myArray = new string/int[,]();
```

Every string will have a corresponding int. But I don't want it for sorting or anything. I know I can use a dictionary and other advanced methods which I know how to use. I want to get simple I want to see in it's simplest form how I can make an array with 2 types like this. The simplest way I can think of is to just use object and then explicitly convert later. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: A dictionary is an advanced class?

Comment: I want my data types to have absolutely nothing but what I need. For example int is just a simple number. Dictionary is advanced because it contains many different methods and constructs which are not necessary. Perhaps this is more of an educational related question. Like the most simple way to do a thing without additional stuff.

Comment: @CodeCamper Dictionary **IS** the most simple way to do this...it maps each string to an int..If it's suitable, that each string meets only once, then it's what you need

Comment: Just curious... why do you need to see it in it's simplest form?

Comment: Use the best data structure for the job, not the one that has as little utility as possible.  Having more than the minimum utility is not what makes anything "advanced".

Comment: @vivekmaharajh everyone says not to use `goto` but it helps me understand loops as to how they exactly work and by understanding them rather than avoiding them because they are ultra simple I can actually use them in situations where there is no need for a complicated structure. Likewise I would like to see array structures at their most basic level and add up as needed. I like to fully understand every part of the thing I am using unless I absolutely can't.

Comment: @Amy Sure the word advanced is relative. But as an example I just wanted to generate some labels dynamically I could visualize a very simple array and for loop where I could declare my labels instead of making them in the designer. I just wanted 1 string and 1 integer and I thought it was bad that I couldn't think of the most basic structure to use to resolve this. I found object to be the most simple except for the explicit conversion part. For example if I want to repeat a piece of code but don't want it in a method I use goto simple and exactly what I want.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I realize that my question could have come off as being slightly insulting. We all have different mental approaches and it is refreshing to hear of new ones. Best of luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use the `Tuple` class.  You can use `Tuple` with generic parameters to combine classes to form tuples.  For example, `Tuple<string, int>` or `Tuple<string, int, int?, char>`.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx) is documentation of the 2-parameter version.  In the case you described, you probably want an instance of type `Tuple<string, int>[]`.

You can access the elements of the `Tuple` using the `ItemX` methods: `myTuple.Item1`, `myTuple.Item2`, etc.

In order to actually create the tuples, I recommend using the `Tuple.Create` methods.  For example: `Tuple.Create("hello", 1)` will return a `Tuple<string, int>` with the items set correctly.  These `Create` methods allow you to omit the generic parameters.

As a side note, you mentioned that you don't need sorting.  You can get arbitrary sorting rather easily by performing a LINQ query on the new `Tuple<string, int>` (which implements `IEnumerable<Tuple<string, int>>`, and so you can perform LINQ's `IEnumerable` extensions on it).  For example, in order to order by the `int` part and then the `string part of the tuple, you could do:

```
 myTupleArray.OrderBy(t => t.Item2).ThenBy(t => t.Item2);
```

Also look at `OrderByDescending` and `ThenByDescending` for more options.

Comment: +1. Also I think [KeyValuePair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx) is 1% simpler :).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I think the `Tuple` abstraction provides a little bit more, since (1) it is extendible to more than 2 types, (2) the documented semantics of `KeyValuePair` make it strange to use in certain cases (where one value is a key and the other a value) and (3) I like the generic-free `Create` method which you get for free.  But yeah I generally agree that `KeyValuePair` can be used here too :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `Object` class.

```
Object[] myarray = {string1,int1,string2,int2}
```

If you want to group the `strings` and `ints` you can do this:

```
Object[][] myarray = { {string1,int1}, {string2,int2} };
myarray[0][0] = string1 and myarray[0][1]=int1
```

Answer (score 1):

The tuple would be a great choise like ben also said,but if you only want to work with arrays to achieve that result maybe something like this..

```
            Array[] m = new Array[2];

            m[0] = new string[10]{"2","5","7","9","12","53","11","36","39","4"};
            m[1] = new int[10] { 2, 5, 7, 9, 12, 53, 11, 36, 39, 4 };

            int val = (int)m[1].GetValue(3);
            string str = (string)m[0].GetValue(3);
```

Comment: I will mark this as the answer if you can make it so I do not have to cast the type! Because doing an array like this is really cool. Never thought of this.